# how to make a actor slide off the right-hand side of the screen and then reset back to the left

Tags: python, pygame

Sorry if the question is stupid. I have just started out coding in a library called pygame zero. I'm having problem translating this code:

```
if actor.left > WIDTH:

actor.right = 0
```

Instead of it going of the right and then showing up on the left, I would like it to be able go off to the left and then appear on the right. Sorry again if this is a newbie question but any help is appreciated!

Here is the full code

```
    import pgzrun

    WIDTH = 1200
    HEIGHT = 700
    music.play('music1')
    chick = Actor('chick')
    chick.pos = 100, 550 
    hippo = Actor('hippo')
    hippo.pos = 1100, 550 

    def draw():
        screen.blit('background1', (0,0))  
        chick.draw()  
        hippo.draw()

    def update():

        if chick.left > WIDTH:
            chick.right = 0
        if hippo.left > WIDTH:
            hippo.right = 0

    if keyboard.left:
        hippo.x = hippo.x - 2 #contols for hippo
        hippo.angle += 3 #rotation effect
    if keyboard.right:
        hippo.x = hippo.x + 2 #contols for hippo
        hippo.angle -= 3 #rotation effect
    if keyboard.a:
        chick.x = chick.x - 2 #contols for chick
        chick.angle += 3 #rotation effect
    if keyboard.d:
        chick.x = chick.x + 2 #contols for chick
        chick.angle -= 3 #rotation effect






pgzrun.go()
```

Comment: What exactly do the attributes left and right mean?

Comment: I guess `actor` is a `Rect`? You should post a bit more of your code, so that we can understand better.

Comment: updated it with all the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your existing code, you handle walking out at the right side. To handle walking out of the right side you need to add one new if statement for each actor. you can add id right under your existing if statements.

```
"""Your existing code"""
if chick.left > WIDTH:
    chick.right = 0
if hippo.left > WIDTH:
     hippo.right = 0 
""""My new code"""
if chick.right < 0:
    chick.left = WIDTH   # Maybe change to WIDTH - 1 to make it visible
if hippo.right < 0:
    chick.left = WIDTH # Maybe change to WIDTH - 1 to make it visible
```

[image: Layout of your window with actor]

I think this image could help to understand what is going on. The important part to understand that the window is like a coordinate system. 0 is at the left side and WIDTH at the right.

If the coordinate of `actor.right` is less then 0 (`if chick.right < 0:`) The actor fully moved out at the left side. So you have to set its left value to be on the right edge. This way the actor is moved to the most right side. You can think of this like you have a real rectangle and you move the left edge of the rectangle to a position. In this case position `WIDTH`. this should become more clear when you try setting other values than `WIDTH`.

Try for example `chick.left = WIDTH/2 # move it nearly to the center` or `chick.left = 20`.

To move it exactly to the center:

```
width_actor = actor.right - actor.left
if actor.right < 0:
    actor.left = WIDTH/2 - width_actor/2
```

Just experiment and you should understand what is going on.

Comment: that works but then the code i put above does not seem to work

Comment: Ok, can you add more of your code, that we can find the problem? You can edit your question at the edit button under the tags. All code must be intended with 4 spaces. Intended code in python then needs 8 spaces and so on

Comment: Ok, I've updated my code. Does this work or do you need an explanation?

Comment: thank you so much, it works could you explain how though ?

Comment: Does this help or do you need help at any other part?

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!  I now understand :)